# Searching geodetic databases for historical landmarks in Canada by Station names (or numbers)

Tags: geolocation, canada

I am interested in historical landmarks within Canada.  I have a Station name ... Station 08U1209.  I would like to read what information is available about it from our Canadian Geodatic database, but I have tried for hours now to access this database.  I cannot seem to find it.

If it exists, then how do I access it?

Comment: This is just the first one in many that I would like to begin to access.  I also geocache and will be referencing this database if it exists.  There is one in the states called USDS, I think, and I have used it.

Comment: by name example: Ontario https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_National_Historic_Sites_of_Canada_in_Ontario top right map all coordinates?

Comment: Would there be a counterpart for Geodetic Survey Markers as well?
I assumed that the Station number on each survery marker would be recorded somewhere.  I suppose the only question is it available online and available to the general public?

For instance ... I was looking for the benchmark that was registered in 1908 as Station 08U1209... 

ROMAN CATHOLIC CHURCH, BOLT IN STONEWORK OF SOUTH SIDEWALL, 60CM WEST OF FIRST PILASTER EAST OF TOWER, 30CM ABOVE BASEMENT WINDOW-SILL

This one was for a geocache mystery, but the data would be invaluable for ref.

THanks to @Mapperz for your help

Comment: You might need to contact the Directory of Federal Heritage Designations they might have the information that you require or point you in the right direction https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/culture/dfhd/contact.aspx